# Sessions in Azure: client side sessions possible?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, azure, azure-web-roles

As you already know, due to the missing sticky session functionality, session information in Azure web roles have to be stored in places like SQL Azure or the Appfabric Cache when using multiple role instances. I know this is the best approach - but apart from that, would it also be possible to store sessions on client side like described [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)? I can imagine using cookies would be easy, but what about the other solutions mentioned there? I'm not going to do this, I'm just interested in how reliable such a solution would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these options are all available.

As far as the client side is concerned there's no discernible difference between an ASP.NET site running on Azure from any other kind of ASP.NET site.

If you know you are working with clients with reasonably recent browsers (such as mobile devices) you may find HTML 5 storage is also an option. See here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/